# Replacing drywall panels: butt or tapered edge?

Tags: drywall, mudding, taping

When re-opening walls for plumbing, electrical changes I elected to remove whole drywall panels, when replacing these with new panels should I present a tapered edge to the previously finished edge?  Or does it now count as a "butt edge" and should I cut the drywall for a butt-to-butt edge?

I'm reading that it's more difficult to finish a taper-to-butt seam.

In one case the paper tape came up easily, should I do elsewhere?

I'll be hiring a taper/mudder to re-finish these seams.

Comment: Is “mudder” a plasterer?

Comment: *I'll be hiring a taper/mudder to re-finish these seams.* Maybe ask that person which seam style they prefer to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finishing a taper to butt seam is no more difficult than any other seam. Don't worry about it. (Especially if you've got a pro doing it.)

Any paper that lifts should be removed.